# pasar variable en loop entre páginas con sessions

Tags: php, loops, session

He iniciado sesión en dos páginas. En ambas tengo una variable global de sesión. En la primera página esta variable está dentro de un loop. Lo que trato de hacer es enviar un valor de variable distinto dependiendo de donde se haga el link. Si es el primer link que se envíe el primer valor de la variable, si es el segundo, el segundo valor..., pero el valor que se envía siempre es el mismo.

pagina1.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pagina 1</title>
</head>
    
<body>
    <h1>Página 1</h1>
    
    <!--inicio sesion-->
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    
    <div class="capitulos">
        
        <!--inicio bucle for con variable de sesión-->
        <?php
        for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) :
        $_SESSION['var'] = $a;
        ?>
    
        <!--textos con vínculos y con variable de sesión-->
        <a href="pagina2.php">
            <?php echo "capítulo" . $a; ?> <br>
        </a>
        
        <!--cierro bucle for-->
        <?php
        endfor; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

pagina2.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pagina 2</title>
</head>
    
<body>
    <h1>Página 2</h1>
    
    <?php
    session_start();
    
    //muestro variable de sesión anterior    
    echo $_SESSION['var']; 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se te envía todo el rato el último valor porque dentro del bucle estás sobreescribiendo todo el rato la misma variable `$_SESSION['var']`.

Answer (score 2):

El valor es siempre el mismo porque lo que está ocurriendo dentro del `for` es lo siguiente:

En el primer paso:

```
$_SESSION['var'] = 0
```

En el segundo paso:

```
$_SESSION['var'] = 1
```

En el tercer paso:

```
$_SESSION['var'] = 2
```

Con lo cual sea cual sea el que pulses, el valor de la sesión `var` siempre será el último asignado, en este caso el 2. Te recomiendo hacerlo de otra manera, usando `$_GET`. En vez de dirigir al usuario a pagina2.php hazlo así:

```
<a href="pagina2.php?capitulo=<?=$a?>">
```

Y después en la página 2 podrás recuperar el número de capítulo así:

```
echo $_GET['capitulo'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasarlo con la variable [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php).

**Pagina 1:**

```
<?php for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) { ?>

<a href="pagina2.php?var=<?php echo $a; ?>">

    <?php echo "capítulo" . $a; ?>
</a>

<?php } ?>
```

**Pagina 2:**

```
if (isset($_GET['var'])){

    $_SESSION['var'] = $_GET['var'];
}
```

Opción con `<form>` y [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php):

**Pagina 1:**

```
<?php for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) { ?>

    <form action="pagina2.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="var" value="<?php echo $a; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Capítulo <?php echo $a; ?>">
    </form>   

<?php } ?>
```

**Pagina 2:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['var'])) {

        echo $_POST['var'];
    }
}
```

Luego le puedes dar estilo al `<input type="submit...>"` para que aparenta como un link si quieres.

Comment: Entonces no es necesario abrir sesiones. Habrá alguna forma de validar la seguridad escondiendo, por ejemplo, la última parte de la url?

Comment: @virtual8870 - En verdad no es necesario pasarlo a una `$_SESSION` si lo usas solo para la `pagina 2`... He actualizado mi respuesta con otra opción para pasar *escondido* vía `post` los valores. Pero recuerda si no se envía por un protocolo seguro `HTTPS` se puede captar aún así las informaciones enviados.